# Show that positive definite and symmetric matrix determinant inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, positive-definite

I have a n by n matrix $A$ is defined as follows:

$$
  A_1 = \begin{bmatrix} a_0 \end{bmatrix},
  A_2 = \begin{bmatrix} a_0 & a_1 \\\ a_1 & a_0 \end{bmatrix},...,
  A_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix} a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \\\ a_1 & a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & a_{n-1} \\\ a_2 & a_1 & a_0 & \cdots & a_{n-2} \\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\ a_n & a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & \cdots & a_0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

For all n, $A_n$ is positive definite and symmetric. Now I would like to show that the inequality holds:

$$
  det A_{n+1} \le \dfrac{(det A_n)^2}{detA_{n-1}}
$$

From the positive definite property, I am sure that all the determinants are all positive based on the Jacobi determinant. Also, the eigenvalues of $A_n$ are all positive in this case. Yet, I have no idea about how to use those properties to prove the listed inequality. Where should I start from?

Comment: Thanks! Did not notice this post.

Comment: Well, not quite. I am still trying to comprehend the proof at that post, and I am considering if there is any other proof for this question. I have written some of the attributes regarding positive definite matrix for prooving this though, it does not work as expected. With some days of research,  I think the Schur theorem probably can provide some clues for this.

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly is not clear in the proof from the link?

Comment: Hmm... I am actually figuring this part  $\dfrac{\det{T_{k-1}}}{\det{T_k}}\le\dfrac{\det{T_k}}{\det{T_{k+1}}}$ or equivalently (since $X^{-1}=\frac{\operatorname{adj} X}{\det X}$), $(T_k^{-1})_{11}\le(T_{k+1}^{-1})_{11}.$ It looks quite reasonable, yet, I am not sure why two determinant can be expressed in this way.

Comment: Also, I have searched for Schur Theorem, and the block matrix decomposition, but I think I still need some time to comprehend.